# How to fill page width with character in iText 7

Tags: java, width, itext7, paragraph

I'm messing around a little bit with iText 7 pdf in Java, and was looking for a solution to fill the rest of the page width with an underscore ( _ ) to create a line that the user can write on. Basically a form, however I don't want to use acroforms or anything. I just want a line that stretches across to the page end after each text.

so I have:

```
Name
Address
Phone
```

I want to make it so that it shows this:

```
Name _________________
Address ______________
Phone ________________
```

Where the end of the line would be at the end of the page.

Comment: Something very similar is written up on the iText site under: 
     "How to restrict the number of characters on a single line"

Answer (score 2):

iText 7 has a concept of tabs and tab stops which allows you to specify "control points" (tab stops) and jump to the next control point (by using tabs). Tabs also allow you to configure appearance of the space between the previous cursor position and the next tab stop.

Long story short, here is a code sample that defines a tab stop at the right end of the page, and adds a tab after the text that jumps to that tab stop. We also configure the visual appearance of the line that will be drawn between the right text position and the tab stop. We make the line `0.5` points thick.

```
PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(outFileName));

Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

float pageRightXPos = document.getPdfDocument().getDefaultPageSize().getRight() -
        document.getLeftMargin() - document.getRightMargin();
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Text that should have underscore continuation")
        .add(new Tab()).addTabStops(new TabStop(pageRightXPos, TabAlignment.RIGHT, new SolidLine(0.5f)));
document.add(p);

document.close();
```

Result looks like this:

[image: result]